# Laravel 5 token mismatch with kendo ui grid update

Tags: php, laravel, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, laravel-5

I am trying to execute an update on my kendo ui grid but I keep getting:

```
TokenMismatchException in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 46
```

My code for the update so far is simply:

```
public function update(Request $request)
{
    $data = $request->all();
}
```

How do I fix this?

---

The POST request is:

```
id:1
created_by:1
first_name:Tom
account_name:
net:124.05
created_at:Sun Mar 08 2015 14:43:08 GMT+0000 (GMT Standard Time)
symbol:£
category_id:2
category_name:Drink
type_id:1
type_name:Cash
```

Request headers:

```
Accept:application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Cache-Control:no-cache
Content-Length:201
Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
Cookie:XSRF-TOKEN=eyJpdiI6IjU2cHo3ZVd6KzFWaUlFVFRDV1lVUHc9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoib0pBU00wclJmVU9ROVwvTkxIeDVcL1QwY3EwVlg4YVowemVXQWpDMjVjZVMybEVPK2tjeFwvNlA4STExOWN4WHg3WHdzemN6UlEwTkg1d0haWElGOVoxNnc9PSIsIm1hYyI6ImI0YmI5MzM2YTdlZjlmYjRhNTAyMDU2NWI2NTU5YmFmNWUzODIzZDAxYWVmNTUzZDkyY2Q1MWE1ZWRjZWUzZDAifQ%3D%3D; laravel_session=eyJpdiI6Ik9zaFJ3S2JiM2lvcnJBN01UT29hM2c9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoiblwvbGRtcFRmakdhdzRYV1dUdnZWSzNFb3pjSUdrendrbk5IZVFPWGtDZGF0dmNnMGNDUGxlRzVvQ0cxVWRFeWI0djhzOEY1ZWk4M0Q0WHg3dE1GMENBPT0iLCJtYWMiOiI0YWVmNzFjOTQ5NWU5ODc4MDA0NTVhMmU0M2E3OWZkNGI3NTA1NWE2OWU2YjczYjA3M2NkNTcxMTBhZWZmNzYxIn0%3D
Host:mbms.com
Origin:http://mbms.com
Pragma:no-cache
Proxy-Connection:keep-alive
Referer:http://mbms.com/core/finance/transactions
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/40.0.2214.115 Safari/537.36
X-Requested-With:XMLHttpRequest
```

Answer (score 0):

I seem to have fixed it by doing the following:

```
<div id="incomeGrid" data-csrf="{!! csrf_token()!!}"></div>
```

And in my DS:

```
...
update: {
            url: '/core/income-grid/update',
            dataType: 'json',
            type: 'post',
            data: function(data){
                data._token = $('#incomeGrid').data('csrf');
                return data;
            }
        },
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Include this in your form

```
 <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="<?php echo csrf_token(); ?>"
```

before form close